# Canvas blur filter hanging the browser while rendering big size image like '2000 x 3000'

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, filter, blur

I am trying to make a jquery plugin which filters images through canvas. I have found some filter code from this link

https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/118/index.html

The problem is while I am applying contrast, grayscale effects they are working fine not hanging up browser, smooth running, but when I am using blur effect for big size images like '2000x3000', browser gets hanged.

Here is my plugin code (only for blur is here) ::

```
   (function ($) {
$.fn.canfilter = function (options) {
    var thisobg = $(this);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    thisobg.empty();
    thisobg.append(canvas);
    var context;
    var iW = $(".cropped").find('img').innerWidth(); // image width
    var iH = $(".cropped").find('img').innerHeight(); // image height
    var p1 = 0.99;
    var p2 = 0.99;
    var p3 = 0.99;
    var er = 0; // extra red
    var eg = 0; // extra green
    var eb = 0; // extra blue
    var iBlurRate = 0;
    var func = 'color'; // last used function
     if (options === 'blur1') {
        resetToBlur1();
    }
    else if (options === 'blur2') {
        resetToBlur2();
    }
    else {
        //do default action
    }

    // ------------------------- blur ---------------------
    function Blur() {
        func = 'blur'; // last used function
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = $(".cropped").find('img').attr('src');//$("#image").attr('src');
        canvas.width = iW;
        canvas.height = iH;
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, iW, iH);
        var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, iW, iH);
        var data = imgd.data;
        for (br = 0; br < iBlurRate; br += 1) {
            for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
                iMW = 4 * iW;
                iSumOpacity = iSumRed = iSumGreen = iSumBlue = 0;
                iCnt = 0;
                // data of close pixels (from all 8 surrounding pixels)
                aCloseData = [
                    i - iMW - 4, i - iMW, i - iMW + 4, // top pixels
                    i - 4, i + 4, // middle pixels
                    i + iMW - 4, i + iMW, i + iMW + 4 // bottom pixels
                ];
                // calculating Sum value of all close pixels
                for (e = 0; e < aCloseData.length; e += 1) {
                    if (aCloseData[e] >= 0 && aCloseData[e] <= data.length - 3) {
                        iSumOpacity += data[aCloseData[e]];
                        iSumRed += data[aCloseData[e] + 1];
                        iSumGreen += data[aCloseData[e] + 2];
                        iSumBlue += data[aCloseData[e] + 3];
                        iCnt += 1;
                    }
                }
                // apply average values
                data[i] = (iSumOpacity / iCnt) * p1 + er;
                data[i + 1] = (iSumRed / iCnt) * p2 + eg;
                data[i + 2] = (iSumGreen / iCnt) * p3 + eb;
                data[i + 3] = (iSumBlue / iCnt);
            }
        }
        context.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
    }
    function resetToBlur1() {
        p1 = 1;
        p2 = 1;
        p3 = 1;
        er = eg = eb = 0;
        iBlurRate = 1;
        Blur();
    }
    // -- blur 2
    function resetToBlur2() {
        p1 = 1;
        p2 = 1;
        p3 = 1;
        er = eg = eb = 0;
        iBlurRate = 4;
        Blur();
    }
    // ------------------------- // blur ---------------------    

   };
 }(jQuery));
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="cropped">
        <img id="croppedImg" src="03bc52c30e5eea81e4e816364fe4249a.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div id="panel">
      <!-- viewable canvas -->
    </div>
  <input type="button" id="blur1" value="Blur1" />
  <input type="button" id="blur2" value="Blur2" />
```

And in script ::

```
   $("#blur1").click(function(){
           $("#panel").filter('blur1'); 
        });
   $("#blur2").click(function(){
           $("#panel").filter('blur2'); 
        });
```

I need a simple blur code which will not hang the browser. Please provide me a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I won't go through your code too much, but let's start with one big thing unrelated to your issue : you are not waiting for the image has loaded before drawing it on the canvas. This may work on some UAs, but it will definitely fail on some others.

Now, to the blur problem.

Doing an blur effect yourself on big images will be slow, since you have to iterate multiple times over all the pixels, there is [this lib](https://github.com/flozz/StackBlur), which does a good job, but which may also hangs the browser.

So you may want to run your algo in a Worker to not freeze the main page while doing the calculations, which will still be slow though :

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = init;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/800px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg";

function initWorker() {
  var worker_file = new Blob([worker_script.textContent]);
  var worker_url = URL.createObjectURL(worker_file);
  return new Worker(worker_url);
}

function init() {
  var worker = initWorker();
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  c.width = canvas.width = img.width;
  c.height = canvas.height = img.height;
  var visibleCtx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var amount = 2;
  var blur = 5;
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    visibleCtx.putImageData(e.data, 0, 0);

    blur += amount;
    if (blur > 10 || blur <= 0) {
      amount *= -1;
    }
    blurImage(blur);

  };

  function blurImage(blurRate) {
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    worker.postMessage({
      imageData: imageData,
      blurRate: blurRate
    }, [imageData.data.buffer]);
  }
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  blurImage(blur);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script type="worker-script" id="worker_script">
    onmessage = function(event){
       var d = event.data;
       var imgData = d.imageData.data.length ?
        d.imageData : new ImageData(d.imageData.data, d.imageData.width, d.imageData.height);
    self.postMessage(Blur(imgData, d.blurRate), [imgData.data.buffer]);
    };
   function Blur(imgd, iBlurRate){
    var p1 = 1;
         p2 = 1;
         p3 = 1;
         er = eg = eb = 0;

  var iW = imgd.width;
        var data = imgd.data;
        for (var br = 0; br < iBlurRate; br += 1) {
            for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
                iMW = 4 * iW;
                iSumOpacity = iSumRed = iSumGreen = iSumBlue = 0;
                iCnt = 0;
                // data of close pixels (from all 8 surrounding pixels)
                aCloseData = [
                    i - iMW - 4, i - iMW, i - iMW + 4, // top pixels
                    i - 4, i + 4, // middle pixels
                    i + iMW - 4, i + iMW, i + iMW + 4 // bottom pixels
                ];
                // calculating Sum value of all close pixels
                for (e = 0; e < aCloseData.length; e += 1) {
                    if (aCloseData[e] >= 0 && aCloseData[e] <= data.length - 3) {
                        iSumOpacity += data[aCloseData[e]];
                        iSumRed += data[aCloseData[e] + 1];
                        iSumGreen += data[aCloseData[e] + 2];
                        iSumBlue += data[aCloseData[e] + 3];
                        iCnt += 1;
                    }
                }
                // apply average values
                data[i] = (iSumOpacity / iCnt) * p1 + er;
                data[i + 1] = (iSumRed / iCnt) * p2 + eg;
                data[i + 2] = (iSumGreen / iCnt) * p3 + eb;
                data[i + 3] = (iSumBlue / iCnt);
            }
        }
        return imgd;
    }
 </script>
```

But the best solution, when available, is to use the the [`ctx.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property. The browser will do the blurring itself on the GPU :

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = init;
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/800px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg"
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
if(ctx.filter !== 'none'){
  console.warn("your browser doesn't support the filter property," +
   "we should fallback to the getImageData + worker solution");
  throw 'not-supported';
  }
var blur = 5;
var amount = .4;

function init(){
  c.width = this.width;
  c.height = this.height;
  draw();
  }

function draw(){
  blur = blur + amount;
  if(blur > 20 || blur <=0){
    amount *= -1;
    }
  ctx.filter = 'blur('+blur+'px)';
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```